# CUDA brute force fun

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, brute-force

I'm a CUDA newbie only started learning how to program CUDA to solve this problem. Would love some opinions on how I can improve the code and GPU utilisation. Running GTX 980 btw.

I created a problem for fun that requires any group of 8 players out of 266 to form a team. Aim is to get highest total average points (each player has a specific point average) for the team whilst under budget constraints (each player costs specific amount of money). Sort of like a fantasy sport team problem.

I want to see how fast I can brute force the massive amount of combinations (not really interested in optimisation algos at this stage).

I currently create array's for player details.

```
    ifstream file("D:\\Players.txt");
    string content;
    while (file >> content){
        if (j == 0){
           name[i] = content;
        }
        else if (j == 1){
           price[i] = stoi(content);
        }
        else if (j == 2){
           avg[i] = stoi(content);
        }
        else if (j == 3){
           tot[i] = stoi(content);
        }
        j++;
        if (j == 4){ j = 0; i++; }
     }
```

Then generate 8 arrays that are the starting index for an 8 nested for loop (generated the list.txt before).

```
    while (output >> content){ //33002854 number of rows row ind
      if (j == 0) pos[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 1) pos1[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 2) pos2[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 3) pos3[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 4) pos4[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 5) pos5[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 6) pos6[ind] = stoi(content);
      else if (j == 7) pos7[ind] = stoi(content);
      j++;
      if (j == 8){ j = 0; ind++; }
    }
```

Then pass all this to the kernal. Each thread reads it's starting point from that array first.

```
    for (q = 0; q < rowcount - 7; q++){
        if (stopper == 0) q = pos[x];
        for (w = q + 1; w < rowcount - 6; w++){
            if (stopper == 0) w = pos1[x];
            for (e = w + 1; e < rowcount - 5; e++){
               if (stopper == 0) e = pos2[x];
               for (r = e + 1; r < rowcount - 4; r++){
                  if (stopper == 0) r = pos3[x];
                  for (t = r + 1; t < rowcount - 3; t++){
                     if (stopper == 0) t = pos4[x];
                     for (y = t + 1; y < rowcount - 2; y++){
                        if (stopper == 0) y = pos5[x];
                           for (u = y + 1; u < rowcount - 1; u++){
                             if (stopper == 0) u = pos6[x];
                                for (i = u + 1; i < rowcount; i++){
                                if (stopper == 0) {
                                    i = pos7[x]; stopper = 1;
                                }
```

Where x = threadIdx.x, rowcount = 266.

There's around 286,853,510,505,870 total loops to complete if you where to do it on one thread start to finish. I've cheated a little and added some smarts to jump ahead in the nested loops by sorting the data so if price > budget at any position skip to next position that wont be > budget.

Then evaluate the loop and if price < budget and avg > current max average save loop index so I can get player names and avg score to compare with the other threads later.

```
    for (i = u + 1; i < rowcount; i++){
        if (stopper == 0) {
            i = pos7[x]; stopper = 1;
        }

        p[0] = price[q] + price[w] + price[e] + price[r] + price[t] + price[y] + price[u] + price[i];
        if (p[0] < budget){
            a[0] = avg[q] + avg[w] + avg[e] + avg[r] + avg[t] + avg[y] + avg[u] + avg[i];
            if (a[0] > maxavg[x]){
                thread[x] = loopcounter;
                maxavg[x] = a[0];
            }
            loopcounter++;
        }
        else {
           loopcounter = loopcounter + rowcount - i;
           i = rowcount;
        }
        if (loopcounter >= count){return;}
    }
```

count = 16936750 which is the number of loops between each thread.

Pass thread[] and maxavg[] back to host and then a for loop through maxavg[i] to find highest value and print the thread[].

## Question 1

I'm curious how safe this line is

```
    thread[x] = loopcounter;
    maxavg[x] = a[0];
```

Without atomic functions will this see any clashes? When I wrote it I thought it was an excellent way to allow each thread to share its solution with global memory without any slow downs/clashes. Could it be writing a[0] from another thread into maxavg[x] or loopcounter?

## Question 2

How can I speed this up? To complete this would need 33002854 threads.

```
   addKernel <<<32230, 1024>>>(dprice, davg, dpos, dpos1, dpos2, dpos3, dpos4, dpos5, dpos6, dpos7, dthread, dmaxavg);
```

I ran last night with 1024 blocks and threads

```
    addKernel <<<1024, 1024>>>(dprice, davg, dpos, dpos1, dpos2, dpos3, dpos4, dpos5, dpos6, dpos7, dthread, dmaxavg);
```

and I stopped it after not finished in 13 hours. Since I have 2048 CUDA cores does that mean if 100% utilised I should be able to run 2048 threads at the same time `addKernel <<<2048, 1>>>`? Or more like `addKernel <<<2048, 1024>>>`? I can then resize the for loop gaps to fit this shape.

Happy to post the code if required (it's long so didn't want to add more to this big post).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as there's a budget, this is a knapsack problem. Brute force is unnecessary. CPU could calculate this  almost instantly with a proper algorithm.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I tried knapsack optimisation in the beginning and must have missed something because I couldn't see how it would achieve a speedup in this case due to every combination still needing to be evaluated. e.g. in the wiki example w[] would be 8 dimensional and n = 286,853,510,505,870. for i from 1 to n do:

    for j from 0 to W do:

        if w[i-1] > j then:

            m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]

        else:

            m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i-1]] + v[i-1])

Comment: @matt please read more about dynamic programming. You problem is the 0/1 knapsack problem. n=266 in your case. You only need to calculate m[i,W], where i=8, W is your budget and m[i, W] is the highest points with 8 players and budget W.